# How to convert List<Object> into List<Map<String,String>> in java8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I know how to convert `List<Object>` into `Map<String,String>` as you can
see in this code:

```
Map<Long, String> divMap = divs.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Div::getId, Div::getName));
```

The output of this is:

> "1": "A", "2": "B"

But I want to return `List<Map<String,String>>`
        with the output given below:

> ["id":"1",Name="A"] ["id":"2",Name="B"]

Comment: Try using Map<String, String> result1 = list.stream().collect(
                Collectors.toMap(string1, string2));, Collectors.toMap is an API fpr doing that

Comment: Please read the question carefully this is what i was doing but i want to return List <Map<String,String> not Map<String,String>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way would be to help yourself by writing a separate `toMap` helper method that converts a `Div` into a `Map<String, String>`.

```
private Map<String, String> toMap(Div div) {
    Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("id", div.getId().toString());
    result.put("name", div.getName());
    return result;
}
```

...and **everything becomes much easier then**:

```
List<Map<String, String>> divMap = divs.stream()
  .map(this::toMap)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Also, it looks like you are trying to reinvent a wheel. Consider using some serialization/deserialization libraries.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Stream's [`reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html) method, like:

```
final List<Div> divs = Arrays.asList(
       new Div("1", "A"),
       new Div("2", "B")
);

final List<Map<String, String>> result = divs.stream()
       .reduce(new ArrayList<>(), (list, div) -> {
            list.add(new HashMap<String, String>() {{
               put("id", div.getId());
               put("name", div.getName());
            }});
            return list;
        }, (a, b) -> a);
```

Reduce method expects 3 parameters:

- initial value (empty list in this case)
- `BiFunction` that provides 2 parameters: accumulator (type `List<Map<String,String>>` in your case) and current value taken from stream iteration (`Div` object) and returns a value of accumulator type
- comparator function (in this case lambda `(a,b) -> a` is enough.

This approach pretty similar to [folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)) known from functional programming.

Comment: The `reduce` is an overkill, check my answer :)

Comment: @GrzegorzPiwowarek Indeed, thumbs up for more clever approach :D :+1: I don't know why I thought of reducing in the very first place :)